# Bootstrap 4.5 behavior change

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a grid with three buttons.  The position of the third button is not the same between Bootstrap 4.4.1 and 4.5.0.

The expected behavior is that the first two buttons are on one line and the third button on another line.

The two snippets have the same minimal code of my page.  In the first snippet I use bootstrap 4.4.1 and behavior is what I expected.  In the second snippet there are the same code but I use bootstrap 4.5.0.  The behavior is the same.

Is it a Bootstrap bug or is it my code that is not correct?

The grid with Bootstrap 4.4.1.  Show the result in fullscreen for best view.

```css
media
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mb-2 text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Plan de protection</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href=""><img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="Bla Bla Bla"></a>
          <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
            <li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col mt-1">
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary text-nowrap" href="">Enregistrer</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col mt-1">
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary text-nowrap" href="">Rechercher</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col mt-1">
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary text-nowrap" href="">Transfert d'un
                                    fichier</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The grid with Bootstrap 4.5.0.  Show the result in fullscreen for best view.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mb-2 text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Plan de protection</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href=""><img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="Bla Bla Bla"></a>
          <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
            <li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
            <li>Bla Bla Bla</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col mt-1">
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary text-nowrap" href="">Enregistrer</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col mt-1">
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary text-nowrap" href="">Rechercher</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col mt-1">
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary text-nowrap" href="">Transfert d'un
                                    fichier</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug seems to be fixed in version 4.5.1.